# как проверить сайт на совместимость с php 7.4 версией?

Tags: php, php7.4

на данный момент использую php 7.1
хочу обновиться и перейти на php 7.4

Вопрос: как можно проверить сайт на совместимость с php 7.4 ?

Проверял через phpstorm:
Code -> Run Inspector by Name -> Language

но я не уверен, что этого достаточно.

Что используете вы?

спасибо

Comment: Читаю upgrade guide и постепенно обновляюсь, сразу будет перепрыгнуть думаю сложно, хотя от проекта зависит.

Comment: запускаешь сайт на версии 7.4 и смотришь где и какие ошибки (если будут)

Comment: сайт огромный. функционал большой. проект на легаси. тестов нет. ручками проверять будет сложно. должны ж быть анализаторы кода

Comment: @Alexandr Makovkin, если не используются какие-то сторонние библиотеки или фреймворки, то ничего проверять не надо. В PHP 7.4 сделали небольшое обновление синтаксиса: теперь свойствам класса можно ещё и указывать тип данных (строка, целое число, дробное число, булевой тип или какой-то класс). Но этого делать необязательно. В PHP 7.4 можно вообще использовать синтаксис PHP 5.

Comment: я установил phpshiffer и phpcodechecker и так проверяю.
и еще через phpstorm